# Query string not working inside paging enabled grid view .

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass RegionProjectID column of my grid from query string when ever a user will click on the RegionProjectName field on the grid. I had made RegionProjectname as hyperlink and below you can find the Code also. But this is not working . Please suggest me or help that why it is not working. The pagin is also enabled in my grid view.

```
<asp:GridView ID="ResultGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true"
    DataKeyNames="RegionProjectID" 
    AllowPaging="True" 
    CellPadding="3" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="ResultGridView_PageIndexChanging" 
    OnRowDeleting="ResultGridView_RowDeleting" 
    CssClass="mGrid"
    OnRowEditing="ResultGridView_RowEditing" 
    OnRowUpdating="ResultGridView_RowUpdating" 
    OnRowCancelingEdit="ResultGridView_RowCancelingEdit" 
    PageSize="15" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2"
     OnRowCommand="ResultGridView_RowCommand" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RegionProjectID" HeaderText="Region ID" InsertVisible="False"
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RegionProjectID" Visible="false" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Region Name" SortExpression="RegionProjectName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegion" Width="250px" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RegionProjectName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegion1" runat="server"  Width="250px"></asp:TextBox> 
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" CommandName="Details" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RegionProjectID") %>' Text='<%# Bind("RegionProjectName") %>' runat="server" /> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ShowHeader="False"> 
            <EditItemTemplate> 
              <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton> 
              <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton> 
            </EditItemTemplate> 
            <FooterTemplate> 
              <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="AddNew" Text="Add New"></asp:LinkButton> 
            </FooterTemplate> 
            <ItemTemplate> 
              <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True"  ShowHeader="True" /> 
           <%-- <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Select" ShowSelectButton="True"  ShowHeader="True"/> --%>

        </Columns>
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <%--<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />--%>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>`


protected void ResultGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Details")
        {
            Server.Transfer("Default3.aspx?ID=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString()); 

        } 

        if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
        {

            TextBox txtRegion1 = (TextBox)ResultGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("txtRegion1");
            TextBox txtNatureOFWork1 = (TextBox)ResultGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNatureOFWork1");
            if (txtRegion1.Text != "")
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO RegionAndProjectInfo(RegionProjectName, NatureOFWorkID ) Values('" + txtRegion1.Text + "', '" + ddlnatureOfWork.SelectedValue.ToString() + "')";
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            FillVendorGrid();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: *But this is not working* actually doesn't help much, you need to put in some effort with what you are trying to achieve or errors you get.

Comment: Now i tried this:- <asp:templatefield headertext="Region Name" sortexpression="RegionProjectName"> 
        <itemtemplate> 
       <asp:hyperlink id="LinkButton3" navigateurl='Default3.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("RegionProjectID") %>' text='<%# Bind("RegionProjectName")%>' runat="server" />  
    </itemtemplate> 
this time i m able to see the Query string but not correctly formatted, instead of RegionID in URl i am getting like this:-"http://localhost:58683/Default3.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("RegionProjectID") %>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:hyperlink id="LinkButton3" navigateurl='<%# "Default3.aspx?ID=" + Eval("RegionProjectID")%>' text='<%# Bind("RegionProjectName")%>' runat="server" />  
                </ItemTemplate>
```

I had updated the itemtemplate of Regionprojectname as above and now getting query string .

Answer (score 0):

You must use

`Response.Redirect("Default3.aspx?ID=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());`

instead of Server Transfer, cause Server Transfer does a different thing compared to Response.Redirect.

The Server.Transfer method also has a second parameter—"preserveForm". If you set this to True, using a statement such as

```
`Server.Transfer("Default3.aspx?ID=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString()`, True);
```

, the existing query string and any form variables will still be available to the page you are transferring to.

its more of a file transfer, instead of a redirect

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I already used this before , the problem is that i had used Paging in the grid so when i am debugging , i found that e.CommandArgument.ToString(); giving "" value.No RegionID is coming in the querystring.